# Approval Workflow for share point

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

Hello I am new for SPD I want to create an approval Workflow . Here is the requirements. Thanks

- The user submits the form.
- An approver (manager) gets an email telling them a form needs to 
  be reviewed and then they can go and either approve or the decline the form.
- If the form is approved an email is sent to a developer (me) notifying 
  them that a new site needs to be created.
- If the form is declined an email is sent to the submitter notifying them 
  of the reason the form was declined.

Answer (score 1):

here is what you asking for

[image]

let me know if you need more help

Comment: I don't see "Assign a task to..." on my SPD 2010

Comment: Could you send me each steps of screen shout ? appreciated

Comment: alright, so you use SharePoint 2010

Comment: hope this video help you https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Create-an-approval-workflow-in-SharePoint-Designer-2010-d7497373-964f-4470-a7d3-aa25cc84c050